# Indentation for JavaScript files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, indentation

What is wrong with VS Code? I claim this is the only editor that causes this problem. Why cannot I indent the lines of a JavaScript file automatically not manually?. In this screenshot (for example), I have a single line inside the if statement. This line should be indented automatically with using `tab` button. Is there any efficient solution for this problem? I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: install ```ESLINT``` or ```PRETTIER``` extension or both.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "indented automatically when using `tab`"?

Comment: I installed both of them with no vain.

Comment: I mean that the single line inside the if statement should be indented two tabs (or whatever) to the right. @zcoop98

Comment: enable lint on save in ```eslint``` extension configuration.

Comment: Do you mean (enable ESLINT as a formatter)? @cybercoder

Comment: ```"eslint.run": "onSave"``` on settings and ```"eslint.format.enable": true,```

Comment: Can you tell me the steps please? I`m stuck. I will be so grateful. @cybercoder

Answer (score 0):

This is my `.eslintrc.js` file in my `babel-node` project root:

```js
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module",
    },
    "plugins": [
        "prettier"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error", {"singleQuote": true, "parser": "flow", "printWidth": 120}],
    }
};
```

And this is my `package.json` file (a part of dev dependencies):

```
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
```

When there is the `rc` file and linter or prettier package(s) are installed local or global, then extension will react. See [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode)